# Is there still a free CDDB database left?

Tags: api, audio, mp3

I'm building a program that needs to interact with a cd database. Googling showed me projects like freedb or gnudb, but it seems those are long dead (last activity on freedb's forum is 2007 before it got flooded with spam). Freedb still works, but is not maintained, and returns messy results. Does anyone know of an active CDDB project that is accessible freely?

Comment: http://musicbrainz.org/doc/FreeDB_Gateway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although there's no strict CDDB service I can find, MusicBrainz offers a web service that can do the same things and more. It also emulates a CDDB, more info on the link Brad provided.

You can access it at http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/

Information on the API here: http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/XMLWebService